# How to enlarge RAID5 array with MegaRAID WebBIOS?

Tags: bios, filesystems, raid

I'm a little confused with RAID5. I created a RAID5 array group from WebBIOS with 6 drives. Then created an XFS partition on this RAID5 drive.

How can I enlarge the RAID5 without losing data?

In WebBIOS I can't find an option to enlarge the drive, only to add additional `Drive group`.

Card module: `LSI MegaRAID 9271-4i`

Comment: "Enlarge" it in what way? Add an additional drive to the array?

Comment: Congratulations on the only correct spelling of "losing" on the internet.  Do you have an `Adv Opers` menu in the drive group?  There should be an option there to add a drive to an existing group.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue. I needed to add a drive to an existing RAID 5 array. 
I'm using MegaRAID WebBios v.6.1-65-Rel
On the home screen you click on "Virtual Drives" then highlight the VD that you want to adjust. Then click the properties button, followed by "GO". This will take you to the properties window for your Virtual Drive Array. In the "Operations" section, click on Advanced Operations (Adv Opers), and again click "GO."

There should now be two windows on the left side of your screen. The top window shows a list of all drives currently included in your array. The bottom window shows any and all drives available to be added to your array. Directly above the bottom window should be a button to add a selected drive to your array. I'm working from memory here, but I believe the button was labeled "Change RAID and add drive." Anyways, you also have the option to change the RAID type while you're adding a new drive. Once you've selected the new RAID type and added the new drive you simply click "GO" again and the RAID migration begins.

I am adding a 4th 4-TB drive to my RAID 5 array, so the process is going quite slowly, and may take through the weekend. I'll report back if I run into any issues.